# Why does "weak.lock()" return "nullptr" with the definition of "auto weak=std::make_shared<int>(42);"?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Why does `weak.lock()` return `nullptr` in this code snippest:

```
   std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr1 = std::make_shared<int>(6);
   std::cout << weakPtr1.lock() << std::endl;
```

whereas it works in the following one:

```
   std::shared_ptr<int> sharedPtr = std::make_shared<int>(99);
   std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr2 = sharedPtr;
   std::cout << weakPtr2.lock() << std::endl;
```

Check cpp.sh/9gkys.

I have thought and thought about it, but I am still confused now. I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

Comment: Because (1) points at an already released resource

Comment: Weak pointers are only valid while there's a strong (shared_ptr) around to keep the object alive. In your first snippet the shared_ptr is released immediately.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Could you please explain that in more detail? What confuses me is the temporary shared object(i.e. `std::make_shared<int>(6)`) is assigned to `weak1` and why it doesn't increase the lifetime of the temporary object?

Comment: @John It only extends the lifetime of its control block, (not the resource itself), where the use counter becomes `0` as soon as the temporary is destroyed, hence it knows it can't be locked any more.

Comment: The whole point of weak pointers is that they **don't** extend the lifetime of the shared object.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki & Raymond Chen  How can I comprehend your comments in the right way? Quote from RaymondChen's comment[emphasis mine]: The whole point of weak pointers is that they **don't extend the lifetime of the shared object.**.  Quote from Piotr Skotnicki's comment[emphasis mine]:  **It only extends the lifetime of its control block**.

Comment: @John Writing an answer takes time...

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thank you for the generous help and patience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart pointers, in order to do their work properly, maintain a so called *control block* which serves as a metadata storage, in particular, use counters. That is, each resource has an associated control block in memory (consisting of e.g. two integers) that smart pointers can refer to to know how many of them are still using/observing the resource. Obviously, each existing `std::shared_ptr` increases the use counter stored in the control block, so that its destructor knows whether or not it's time to release the resource on destruction. `std::weak_ptr`, in turn, only tracks the object and its control block. Note that here's an important detail: `std::weak_ptr` does not increase the use counter. That's desirable, as its main purpose is to break possible cycles between a pair of objects observing one another. That is, if two objects would store `std::shared_ptr`s one to another, then such a pair of objects would also keep alive one another endlessly.

How can a `std::weak_ptr` know if the resource can be `lock()`ed ? This can succeed only if the use counter is greater than zero. It knows that from the control block (which itself remains alive in memory as long as there's also non-zero weak pointers observing it).

In the first example:

```
std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr1 = std::make_shared<int>(6);
```

both a resource (`int=6`) is allocated and also its control block. Use counter becomes `1`, and remains so as long as `std::shared_ptr` is alive. Then, a `std::weak_ptr` is initialized, obtaining a pointer to the control block. Here, it won't increase the use counter. It will, however, increase the counter of weak pointers. At this point, both counters are `1`. Then, at the semicolon `;`, the temporary `std::shared_ptr` is destroyed. It decreases the use counter down to `0`. This means there are no more shared pointers sharing ownership of the resource, which allows that resource to be released. However, there is still `1` weak pointer observing the control block, which means the control block itself will remain in the memory, so that `weakPtr1` knows it won't be able to `lock()` the resource anymore (because that resource no longer exists).

In the second example:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> sharedPtr = std::make_shared<int>(99);
std::weak_ptr<int> weakPtr2 = sharedPtr;
```

both the resource `int=99` and its control block remain alive. Hence `weakPtr2` can be locked as long as `sharedPtr` (or any of its copies) is not destroyed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had been confused for a time, I understand it now with your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your examples use copy initialization. As such, the `shared_ptr` constructed on the right lives only until the evaluation of the expression, and is then destroyed:

1. In the first example this means there are no more references to the shared_ptr (we do not count the weak one), and hence `lock` returns null.
2. In the second one you bind the result to a local variable, extending life time to the current block - and hence there is still a reference, and no null result.